# Netty as High Performant Http Server to Handle ~2-3 Million Requests/Sec

Tags: java, http, client-server, netty

We are trying to Solve the Problem of Handling Huge Volume of Http POST Requests, and while using Netty Server, I was able to handle only `~50K requests/sec` which is too low.

My question is how to tune this Server to ensure to handle `> 1.5 million requests/second`?

**Netty4 Server**

```
// Configure the server.
EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
try {
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
        b.option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 1024);

        b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
         .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
         .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
         .childHandler(new HttpServerInitializer(sslCtx));

        Channel ch = b.bind(PORT).sync().channel();

        System.err.println("Open your web browser and navigate to " +
                (SSL? "https" : "http") + "://127.0.0.1:" + PORT + '/');

        ch.closeFuture().sync();
    } finally {
        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
```

**Initializer**

```
    public class HttpServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    private final SslContext sslCtx;

    public HttpServerInitializer(SslContext sslCtx) {
        this.sslCtx = sslCtx;
    }

    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
        ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
        if (sslCtx != null) {
            p.addLast(sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc()));
        }
        p.addLast(new HttpServerCodec());
        p.addLast("aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        p.addLast(new HttpServerHandler());
    }
}
```

**Handler**

```
public class HttpServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
private static final String CONTENT = "SUCCESS";

@Override
public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    ctx.flush();
}

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    if (msg instanceof HttpRequest) {
        HttpRequest req = (HttpRequest) msg;
        final FullHttpRequest fReq = (FullHttpRequest) req;
        Charset utf8 = CharsetUtil.UTF_8;
        final ByteBuf buf = fReq.content();
        String in = buf.toString( utf8 );
        System.out.println(" In ==> "+in);
        buf.release();
        if (HttpHeaders.is100ContinueExpected(req)) {
            ctx.write(new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.CONTINUE));
        }
        in = null;
        if (HttpHeaders.is100ContinueExpected(req)) {
            ctx.write(new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, CONTINUE));
        }
        boolean keepAlive = HttpHeaders.isKeepAlive(req);
        FullHttpResponse response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, OK, Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(CONTENT.getBytes()));
        response.headers().set(CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain");
        response.headers().set(CONTENT_LENGTH, response.content().readableBytes());

        if (!keepAlive) {
            ctx.write(response).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
        } else {
            response.headers().set(CONNECTION, Values.KEEP_ALIVE);
            ctx.write(response);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause)
{
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: How did you arrive at the number 50k? How did you perform your benchmarking?

Comment: Please google "millions of requests per second". This is a non-trivial problem.

Comment: as I remember a person mentioned implemented one million requests per second at Yahoo. It is not a trivial task for sure.

Comment: @ViktorDahl -  using http benchmarking tool wrk , apache bench i tried sending concurrent request and avg of multiple run gives ~50 K/ sec.

Comment: @OlgaKhylkouskaya - One million also should be good to start and i can scale horizontally to 5 http instance to Handle ~5 million records per/sec which would solve my problem ..

Comment: Thank you @Senthilkumar, it is good to know that you can handle 5 mln per second. Can you please confirm that those are simultaneous connections. Out of curiosity are you doing any db queries on those connections or are they all in memory?

Comment: there is no DB call's its all Kafka Producer Call .. Regarding Connections: Yes all simultaneous conn ...

Answer (score 8):

Your question is very generic. However, I'll try to give you an answer regarding the netty optimizations and your code improvements.

**Your code issues:**

1. `System.out.println(" In ==> "+in);` - you shouldn't use this in high load cocurrent handler. Why? Because code inside `println` method is synchronized and thus gives penalties to your performance;
2. You do 2 class casts. To `HttpRequest` and to `FullHttpRequest`. You may use just last one;

**Netty specific issues in your code:**

1. You need to add epoll transport (in case your server is Linux like). It will give + ~30% out of box; [How to](http://netty.io/wiki/native-transports.html).
2. You need to add native OpenSSL bindings. It will give + ~20%. [How to](http://netty.io/wiki/forked-tomcat-native.html).
3. `EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();` - you need to correctly setup sizes of `bossGroup` and `workerGroup` groups. Depending on your test scenarios. You didn't provide any info regarding your test cases, so I can't give you advice here;
4. `new HttpObjectAggregator(Integer.MAX_VALUE)` - you actually don't need this handler in your code. So for better performance, you may remove it.
5. `new HttpServerHandler()` - you don't need to create this handler for every channel. As it doesn't hold any state it may be shared across all pipelines. Search for `@Sharable` in netty.
6. `new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO)` - you don't need this handler for high load tests as it logs a lot. Make your own logging when necessary;
7. `buf.toString( utf8 )` - this is very wrong. You convert income bytes to string. But this doesn't make any sense as all data is already decoded in netty `HttpServerCodec`. So you do double work here;
8. `Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(CONTENT.getBytes())` - you wrap constant message on every request. And thus - do unnecessary work on every request. You may create ByteBuf only once and do `retain()`, `duplicate()` depending on how you'll do this;
9. `ctx.write(response)` - you may consider using `ctx.write(response, ctx.voidPromise())` in order to allocate less;

This is not all. However, fixing above issues would be a good start.

Comment: This is excellent :) .. I will tune this code and rerun the performance test again .. thanks !

Comment: If i directly cast to FullHttpObject i get below error ... 
so first convert as HttpObj and then Full HttpObj..

java.lang.ClassCastException: 
io.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultHttpRequest cannot be cast to io.netty.handler.codec.http.FullHttpRequest
 at com.akamai.httpserver.netty4.HttpServerHandler.channelRead(HttpServerHandler.java:37)

Comment: Another issue is without adding

`p.addLast("aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator(Integer.MAX_VALUE));`
i could not convert it to FullHttpRequest without using ObjectAggr and  Without converting its difficult to read POST body data ( Using HttpRequest , Can we read POST body contents ? If yes how ? )..

Comment: After tuning this code , still i did not see improvement in Netty Side ...

Comment: Please post improved version of code somewhere. I can't help you with complication errors. As it requires understanding from you how netty works. Also I don't know what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to use Aggregator to receive all chunks together instead of Request, Content , LastContent. 
https://gist.github.com/senthilec566/35374fec8ef8d487c7ab0c88f0e338d4